# Can you use $R^2$ and regression to estimate cause and effect?

Tags: regression, correlation

Does $R^2 * \mbox{slope}$ provide an estimation of cause and effect? For example, if $R^2$ of miles driven and coffee consumed is $x\%$ and the slope of the coffee-and-miles dataset is $y$ (miles/coffee), can you say "$z$ of each cup of coffee drunk is related to the number of miles driven"?

Comment: You are confusing me with using $R^2$ (proportion of data variability explained by the model, not the size of a cause) and estimated marginal effect represented by the slope coefficient (even in a pairwise regression without intercept term) in this strange (non-sensible?) fashion. If you are interested in impacts you may consider beta-coefficients or elasticity coefficients that really do have acceptable interpretation.

Answer (score 5):

Regression gives you, essentially, a correlation. Correlation is not causality -- or else global warming would be caused by a decline in global number of pirates.

Comment: Okay, so let's take warming and pirates.  For example's sake, If the correlation between warming and pirates observed is -.8, (those predominantly tropical swashbucklers just can't seem to stand the heat), the r^2 is 64%.  Let's say the slope of the datasets is something like 1:-10.  Can you say "Of the 10 fewer pirates we saw in a year where the avg temp increased 1 degree, the retirement of about 6 of those brigands could be related to the temperature increase"

Comment: How are there more than one slope? If you regress pirates on global temperatures and find a coefficient of -10, then, for every one degree increase in global temperatures, the number of pirates falls by 10. If the global temperature increase by 0.5 degrees last year, then we expect that there were 0.5*(-10) more (or 5 fewer) pirates.

Comment: The regression only tells you the strength of the possible association, it says precisely nothing about causation.  It can't even tell you the direction of the causal relationship.  In this case, there are multiple confounding variables, so interpreting the regression in this way is very risky and should be accompanied by plenty caveats.